# Appium Java Sauce Labs Cloud testing: Ran Desired Capabilities got Sauce Labs Authentication Error

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios, saucelabs

I'm a noobie on Sauce labs.   I was running my Sauce labs on appium Desired capabilities for the 1st time and I got the following error message:

```
unable to parse remote response: Misconfigured -- Sauce Labs Authentication Error.
You used username 'USERNAME' and access key 'ACCESS_KEY' to authenticate, which are not valid Sauce Labs credentials.
```

My question is this:

1. What is it?
2. How to I fix it?
3. Did I make a newbie error?
4. Silly question but going to ask.  How do I view what's going on in
   sauce labs?

Here is my Desired Capabilities Code:

```
    public static final String USERNAME = "confidential";
    public static final String ACCESS_KEY = "condfidential";
    public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub";

     public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{

         DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

         cap.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
         cap.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone8 Simulator");
         cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "11.3");
         cap.setCapability("browserName", "Safari");
         cap.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");

         WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),cap);

         driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/");
```

Error message:

```
Unable to parse remote response: Misconfigured -- Sauce Labs Authentication Error.
You used username 'USERNAME' and access key 'ACCESS_KEY' to authenticate, which are not valid Sauce Labs credentials.

The following desired capabilities were received:
{'browserName': 'Safari',
 'deviceName': 'iPhone8 Simulator',
 'deviceOrientation': 'portrait',
 'platformName': 'iOS',
 'platformVersion': '11.3'}

Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:42:22.379Z'
System info: host: 'xxx-MacBook-Air.local', ip: '100.100.0.0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.6', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:138)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
    at iOSCloudTesting.IosCloudSauce.main(IosCloudSauce.java:26
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of 'USERNAME' you have to mention your sauce lab username and in place of 'ACCESS_KEY' you should mention sauce lab access key of your account
in following line.

```
WebDriver driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),cap);
```

How to get access key?

1.Login to sauce lab, Click on dashboard.

2.Click your account menu.click on My account.

3.You will find Access key section.

4.Click on show button . It will ask for authorization.

5.Enter password and copy Access key

Comment: Hi I already have the access key and ran the command and I ran the test for the 1st time.  I Got the following message (I have used fake info for security reasons):     'Unable to parse remote response: Misconfigured -- Sauce Labs Authentication Error. Your used username 'ladybug123' and access key '93c3c6d0-9dfa-4039-b723-749a128ceb94@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"),cap);' to authenticate, which are not valid Sauce Labs credentials.'     This makes no sense as I created my account on saturday and I double checked the details.   This is very confusing.

Comment: OK, happy news. 1. I carefully  copy and pasted my USER NAME & ACCESS KEY again  DIRECT from sauce labs.  2. Added them them to the appropriate places in the code.  3  Made a minor change to from  'iPhone8 Simulator'  to 'iPhone 8 Simulator'.  THE TEST RAN PERFECTLY.  THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @fypnlp  you are most welcome. if it helps you then please upvote the answer

Answer (score 1):

For sauce labs, You have to register first, and acquire USERNAME and ACCESS_KEY.

Username You setup yourself in registration process, and access_key is self generated token, which is acquired from following.

1. click on Your username,
2. click "User Settings"
3. click button "Show"
4. input than username and access token in code bellow:

[image]

```
  public static final String USERNAME = "user52";
  public static final String ACCESS_KEY = "Das3$s1";
  public static final String URL = "https://" + USERNAME + ":" + ACCESS_KEY + "@ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 10");
    caps.setCapability("version", "latest");

    //Your issues is with this line. Just run URL string where You previously have setup everything before

    WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);

    driver.get("https://saucelabs.com/test/guinea-pig");

    System.out.println("title of page is: " + driver.getTitle());

    driver.quit();
}
```

So You have like a trial for a week or two, and afterwards is paying. So first acquire username and access key, and run sample code from above.

hope this helps,

Comment: You sir are a legend.  I will do this and you know if it is a success. Thank you so much.

Comment: :) you made me smile. No problem, glad if I could help

Comment: I will get back to you

Comment: Yes. Just take code from answer and input your username and access key, it is tested and it works 100%

Comment: Ok, I will get back to you.

Comment: Ok this is what happened 

'Unable to parse remote response: Misconfigured -- Sauce Labs Authentication Error.
Your used username 'user1' and access key '7151e0az-blah-blah-blah-blah5' to authenticate, which are not valid Sauce Labs credentials. 

How can that be so I only created the account on Saturday!!!

Comment: OK, happy news. 1. I carefully copy and pasted my USER NAME & ACCESS KEY again DIRECT from sauce labs. 2. Added them them to the appropriate places in the code. 3 Made a minor change to from 'iPhone8 Simulator' to 'iPhone 8 Simulator'. THE TEST RAN PERFECTLY. THANK YOU SO MUCH!  IF THERE WAS A WAY TO BUY YOU A DRINK I WOULD.

Answer (score 1):

A couple other thing you may want to check if you are sure your username and access key are right-

1. Check the endpoint. This one would work currently:

   ```
   URL url = new URL("https://ondemand.us-west-1.saucelabs.com/wd/hub");
   ```

I noticed in some of the URLs above, there are:

- `"@ondemand.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub"` this is configured if you are using Sauce Connect and an outbound port of 443
- `http://USERNAME:ACCESS_KEY@ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub` is out of date, and won't work

[See a list of the endpoints you can use for your URL](https://docs.saucelabs.com/basics/data-center-endpoints/)

2. You also want to make sure the `capabilites` (Not Desired capabilities if you are using Selenium 3+) are being used. [You can check/ create a configuration with the platform configurator](https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator)

**TO see on Sauce Labs**
go to app.saucelabs.com. Click on the Automated Testing platform on the left hand side (be sure to switch between real and virtual devices, depending on what you are using) and see test results!